# Antiderivative of a polynomial is always a polynomial?

Tags: integration, polynomials

At first it seems like a simple enough question, but I couldn't quickly find any proofs on this. I would assume that they are, and moreover that the degree is raised by $1$. This is just due to the reverse power rule. Consider what happens if we take the antiderivative of $$a_n x^n + \cdots+ a_1x+a_0,$$

where $a_i$ are real coefficients. The degree would be raised and we would get another zero-degree term in the form of the constant of integration $c$. Is this a total triviality or are there hidden complications?

Edit : $x\in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a total triviality, but it is taken for granted 99.7% of the time.

Comment: I don't see any hidden complications. You can explicitly write down the definite integral of that polynomial, which is again a polynomial.

Comment: @Ramanujan There is the _potential_ for hidden complications in that not all antiderivatives can be written as definite integrals. Sure, those that can be written as definite integrals are polynomials, but what about the others, if they exist? (Which they do: for isntance $x$ doesn't have any definite-integral-antiderivative with negative constant term.)

Comment: @Arthur I don't really see the problem, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Uses_and_properties) states that "each of the infinitely many antiderivatives of a given function f [...] is written using the integral symbol with no bounds: $\int f(x) dx"

Comment: Another complication may be when $x$ is not a real variable.  Say we are talking about coefficients in some other field $F$.  Derivative always makes sense (formally) and is a polynomial;  but possibly not antiderivative, if there are certain coefficients $n+1 = 0$ so you cannot divide by them.

Comment: @Ramanujan The fact that we use an integral symbol for antidifferentiation (and even consider "indefinite integral" and "antiderivative" more or less interchangeable) is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which is far from a triviality. That notation does not, by itself, prove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antiderivative of a polynomial
$$\int a_nx^n+ \cdots + a_1x+a_0 dx=\frac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{2}x^2+a_0x+C$$
I am assuming that $a_i$ are real numbers. We have $n\geq 0$ is an integer, thus $i+1>0$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$. Thus $\frac{a_i}{i+1}$ is a real number. Therefore, result is a polynomial. (One would need an additional condition to solve for $C$).

**Edit**: The argument above does not necessarily hold for a disconnected domain. Consider the following example:

$$f:[0,1]\cup [1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{25pt} \text{ defined by }f(x)=3x^2+1$$
Then, a possible antiderivative is:
$$F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} x^3+x & x \in [0,1] \\ x^3+x+2 & x \in [1,2] \end{array}\right.$$
which is not a polynomial.

Comment: Yes, given a polynomial, _some_ of its antiderivatives are polynomials. I think the crux of the question is whether _all_ antiderivatives are polynomials, and this answer does not really address that.

Comment: @Arthur Ah, I see. I read it too quickly.